# CMake RPATH-handling

Tags: cmake

There is this wiki page about RPATH-handling in CMake: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling#always-full-rpath

They say, that you should only add a directory to RPATH, if it's not a system directory. This makes sense, so I was wondering why they set CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH in any case. Is there something I missed, or is this just a faulty code snippet?

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
...
LIST(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" isSystemDir)
IF("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
   SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
ENDIF("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
```

Comment: "why they suggest to set CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH in any case." - Cannot find "in any case" in the referenced page. The section `Always full RPATH` starts with "**In many cases you will want** to make sure that the required libraries are
always found independent from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the install
location." There is no "required" or "do always" colors in that phrase.

Comment: with "suggest" I meant, that they always set the CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH variable. Later there is an additional check with "LIST(FIND ...", but at that time, the variable is already set.

Comment: The comment `# the RPATH to be used when installing, but only if it's not a system directory` implies that the last part of the snippet should be used instead of the unconditional setting of RPATH. I agree that this is not so obvious, but otherwise the last part has no sence. BTW, the snippet seems to be quite outdated: a comparison of the variable is better to perform **without dereferencing**: `IF(isSystemDir STREQUAL "-1")`.